# What does this lambda function do? (lambda with a function call inside)

Tags: python, lambda

I am reading through some code trying to better understand how it works and I came across this lambda function (I really don't quite get lambda)

```
return lambda **params: self.callMethod(
    aname, rargs, oargs, **params)
```

If possible, does this usage of lambda have a name, so I can perhaps read up on it better? I've seen a few utilizations of lambda but this doesn't seem to fit into what I've seen. Or perhaps I'm just not quite understanding it well enough!

Comment: When this lambda function is called, it will call the `callMethod` function on `self` (the object that contains the lambda function definition), and pass it the arguments specified.

Comment: Judging by the `return`, that's a function that returns a function which calls a function. I'd recommend a critical inspection of whether all that is actually necessary.

Comment: What happens with regards to the `**params`? I don't quite understand the relationship between the first `**params` and the second, if there is one at all.

Comment: **params refers to all the arguments passed to the lambda. The arguments are then passed on to the self.callMethod method.

Comment: Looks like someone wants to write a partial function and didn't want to use `functools.partial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, a function signature can look like

```
def func(arg, *args, **kwargs):
```

Calling `func(1, 123, unnamed=12)` will put 1 in `arg`, `[123]` in args, and `{unnamed => 12}` in kwargs.

The lambda you mentioned takes only named arguments (kwargs), and when written as an actual function would look like :

```
def func(**params):
    self.callMethod(aname, rargs, oargs, **params)
```

Calling that as `func(something=1)` would mean doing `self.callMethod(aname, rargs, oargs, something=1)`, and that's exactly what your lambda will do.